# Shell script to login automatically to a remote linux/AIX server

Tags: bash, shell

My script is suppose to login to a remote server (server2) without prompting for the password from my local server (server1). I have found several articles on google and [tried](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) but my script did not login to the remote server automatically. It is prompting me for`Enter file in which to save the key (/home/eip/.ssh/id_rsa)`; `Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):`; and later it is prompting me to enter remote server password as well. Anyways I answered all the questions but still I was not logged into the remote server. I tried to re-run the script thinking that it will save remote server id and will automatically log me in but still it behaves the same way.

Eventually my script is suppose to login to multiple servers which are passed as parameters and execute some commands on teh remote server.

Below is the piece of my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh $2@$1 mkdir -p .ssh
ssh $2@$1


user1@server1:/home/eip-> ./test.sh server2 user2
Generating public/private rsa key pair.

Enter file in which to save the key (/home/eip/.ssh/id_rsa): 
/home/eip/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y

Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/eip/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/eip/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
7f:a0:03:36:58:09:83:c2:b3:33:b7:a9:33:14:18:fb user1@server1
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|.  .o            |
|oo.  o .         |
|.+o   o          |
|o= . o           |
| .= + + S .      |
| .Eo . o o .     |
|. .     o . .    |
| +       . .     |
|  o              |
+-----------------+

user2@server2 password: password2

Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'user2@server2'", and check in:

  .ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.

user1@server1:/home/eip->
```

Need some guidance on making it work.

Comment: BTW: Looking at your profile I see you've never accepted any answer..

Comment: You can up-vote as many answers as you like and you can choose one most correct to mark as accepted with the green mark - if you can't spot where it's than check a few other questions and you'll find some for sure.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `ssh` is specially designed to prevent you do this that way (passing passphrase from stdin). I would have to dig more to check what it exactly uses but it'll be some kind of `getpass()` (check `man 3 getpass` to read more about it). Main idea is to read it directly from the terminal rather than from stdin. There's one reason for this - security.

Check `sshpass` if you still wish to go that way (but I'm not sure if it can ask for passpharse to a key).

I would suggest you to do one of those two:

1. Use keys without passphrase
2. Find some orchestration solution - for example [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com) is really easy and you'll make much better with it and much faster than struggling with your script.